# Is there an alternative for activatedBackgroundIndicator for API 10

Tags: android, android-layout

```
Android Studio 0.5.7
```

Hello,

```
minSdkVersion 10
targetSdkVersion 19
```

I have a layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator">
</TextView>
```

As this is not available in API 10 I tried to create a new resource layout called `layout-v10` and remove the activatedBackgroundIndicator so only devices running API 10 will use this layout. However, for other layout running API 11 and up,  I will still get the error even though I am targeting up to API 19.

I there an alternative method to get the activatedBackgroundIndicator to work when you are targeting 10 to 19?

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?